# Can I add custom id for a record in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, sql, module, sugarcrm

Can I somehow add a custom id for records in SugarCRM?
I would like to connect records from the database by their ids but they are added automaticly.
Can I write a custom id for them?

Answer (score 0):

The CM & Sugar Sequencing add-on does something similar to this, not sure if it's exactly what you're wanting though: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/cm-sugar-sequencing-addon

Comment: This isn't really what I wanted to do, although thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'd like to edit the autoincrement id in the database from the page where I write the record of the module.

Comment: @user2936389 you could do something like that, but if you have related records to that module you would have to make sure that each of the relationship modules that use the id you want to change are updated as well.

Comment: They don't use the same IDs this is why I'm trying to edit it because I would like to connect them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The ids for records are generated with the create_guid() -function in Sugar. This function will return a uuid (universally unique identifier) as a string, ready for use!